# "pip install PyOpenGL_accelerate" doesn't work on Windows 10 Python 3.7

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, opengl, pyopengl

I'm trying to install **PyOpenGL** on my computer:

- Windows 10, 64 bit
- Python 3.7

Apparently, I need to install both `PyOpenGL` and `PyOpenGL_accelerate` packages.

### 1. Install PyOpenGL

The command `pip install PyOpenGL` works just fine:

```sh
C:\Users\Kristof>pip install PyOpenGL
Collecting PyOpenGL
Installing collected packages: PyOpenGL
Successfully installed PyOpenGL-3.1.0
```

### 2. Install PyOpenGL_accelerate   <sub>(FIRST ATTEMPT)</sub>

The command `pip install PyOpenGL_accelerate` fails:

```sh
C:\Python37\PyOpenGL-accelerate-3.1.0>pip install PyOpenGL_accelerate --no-cache-dir
Collecting PyOpenGL_accelerate
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/d9/74/293aa8794f2f236186d19e61c5548160bfe159c996ba01ed9144c89ee8ee/PyOpenGL-accelerate-3.1.0.tar.gz (323kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 327kB 1.3MB/s
Building wheels for collected packages: PyOpenGL-accelerate
  Building wheel for PyOpenGL-accelerate (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'c:\python37\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Kristof\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-w04pgijy\\PyOpenGL-accelerate\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Kristof\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-w04pgijy\\PyOpenGL-accelerate\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d 'C:\Users\Kristof\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-x4gprfbc' --python-tag cp37
       cwd: C:\Users\Kristof\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-w04pgijy\PyOpenGL-accelerate\
  Complete output (48 lines):
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\OpenGL_accelerate
  copying .\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\OpenGL_accelerate
  running build_ext
  skipping 'src\wrapper.c' Cython extension (up-to-date)
  building 'OpenGL_accelerate.wrapper' extension
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.7
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\src
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -IC:\Users\Kristof\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-w04pgijy\PyOpenGL-accelerate\.. -IC:\Users\Kristof\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-w04pgijy\PyOpenGL-accelerate\src -IC:\Users\Kristof\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-w04pgijy\PyOpenGL-accelerate -Ic:\python37\include -Ic:\python37\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\ATLMFC\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.6.1\include\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\cppwinrt" /Tcsrc\wrapper.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\src\wrapper.obj
  wrapper.c
  src\wrapper.c(3919): warning C4244: '=': conversion from 'Py_ssize_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
  src\wrapper.c(4376): warning C4244: '=': conversion from 'Py_ssize_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
  src\wrapper.c(11474): error C2039: 'exc_type': is not a member of '_ts'
  c:\python37\include\pystate.h(209): note: see declaration of '_ts'
  src\wrapper.c(11475): error C2039: 'exc_value': is not a member of '_ts'
  c:\python37\include\pystate.h(209): note: see declaration of '_ts'
  src\wrapper.c(11476): error C2039: 'exc_traceback': is not a member of '_ts'
  c:\python37\include\pystate.h(209): note: see declaration of '_ts'
  src\wrapper.c(11488): error C2039: 'exc_type': is not a member of '_ts'
  c:\python37\include\pystate.h(209): note: see declaration of '_ts'
  src\wrapper.c(11489): error C2039: 'exc_value': is not a member of '_ts'
  c:\python37\include\pystate.h(209): note: see declaration of '_ts'
  src\wrapper.c(11490): error C2039: 'exc_traceback': is not a member of '_ts'
  c:\python37\include\pystate.h(209): note: see declaration of '_ts'
  src\wrapper.c(11491): error C2039: 'exc_type': is not a member of '_ts'
  c:\python37\include\pystate.h(209): note: see declaration of '_ts'
  src\wrapper.c(11492): error C2039: 'exc_value': is not a member of '_ts'
  c:\python37\include\pystate.h(209): note: see declaration of '_ts'
  src\wrapper.c(11493): error C2039: 'exc_traceback': is not a member of '_ts'
  c:\python37\include\pystate.h(209): note: see declaration of '_ts'
  src\wrapper.c(11536): error C2039: 'exc_type': is not a member of '_ts'
  c:\python37\include\pystate.h(209): note: see declaration of '_ts'
  src\wrapper.c(11537): error C2039: 'exc_value': is not a member of '_ts'
  c:\python37\include\pystate.h(209): note: see declaration of '_ts'
  src\wrapper.c(11538): error C2039: 'exc_traceback': is not a member of '_ts'
  c:\python37\include\pystate.h(209): note: see declaration of '_ts'
  src\wrapper.c(11539): error C2039: 'exc_type': is not a member of '_ts'
  c:\python37\include\pystate.h(209): note: see declaration of '_ts'
  src\wrapper.c(11540): error C2039: 'exc_value': is not a member of '_ts'
  c:\python37\include\pystate.h(209): note: see declaration of '_ts'
  src\wrapper.c(11541): error C2039: 'exc_traceback': is not a member of '_ts'
  c:\python37\include\pystate.h(209): note: see declaration of '_ts'
  error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2017\\Community\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.16.27023\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for PyOpenGL-accelerate
  Running setup.py clean for PyOpenGL-accelerate
Failed to build PyOpenGL-accelerate
Installing collected packages: PyOpenGL-accelerate
  Running setup.py install for PyOpenGL-accelerate ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\python37\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Kristof\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-w04pgijy\\PyOpenGL-accelerate\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Kristof\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-w04pgijy\\PyOpenGL-accelerate\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\Kristof\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-1ulnpq1p\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile
         cwd: C:\Users\Kristof\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-w04pgijy\PyOpenGL-accelerate\
    Complete output (48 lines):
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\OpenGL_accelerate
    copying .\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\OpenGL_accelerate
    running build_ext
    skipping 'src\wrapper.c' Cython extension (up-to-date)
    building 'OpenGL_accelerate.wrapper' extension
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.7
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\src
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -IC:\Users\Kristof\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-w04pgijy\PyOpenGL-accelerate\.. -IC:\Users\Kristof\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-w04pgijy\PyOpenGL-accelerate\src -IC:\Users\Kristof\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-w04pgijy\PyOpenGL-accelerate -Ic:\python37\include -Ic:\python37\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\ATLMFC\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.6.1\include\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\cppwinrt" /Tcsrc\wrapper.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\src\wrapper.obj
    wrapper.c
    src\wrapper.c(3919): warning C4244: '=': conversion from 'Py_ssize_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
    src\wrapper.c(4376): warning C4244: '=': conversion from 'Py_ssize_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
    src\wrapper.c(11474): error C2039: 'exc_type': is not a member of '_ts'
    c:\python37\include\pystate.h(209): note: see declaration of '_ts'
    src\wrapper.c(11475): error C2039: 'exc_value': is not a member of '_ts'
    c:\python37\include\pystate.h(209): note: see declaration of '_ts'
    src\wrapper.c(11476): error C2039: 'exc_traceback': is not a member of '_ts'
    c:\python37\include\pystate.h(209): note: see declaration of '_ts'
    src\wrapper.c(11488): error C2039: 'exc_type': is not a member of '_ts'
    c:\python37\include\pystate.h(209): note: see declaration of '_ts'
    src\wrapper.c(11489): error C2039: 'exc_value': is not a member of '_ts'
    c:\python37\include\pystate.h(209): note: see declaration of '_ts'
    src\wrapper.c(11490): error C2039: 'exc_traceback': is not a member of '_ts'
    c:\python37\include\pystate.h(209): note: see declaration of '_ts'
    src\wrapper.c(11491): error C2039: 'exc_type': is not a member of '_ts'
    c:\python37\include\pystate.h(209): note: see declaration of '_ts'
    src\wrapper.c(11492): error C2039: 'exc_value': is not a member of '_ts'
    c:\python37\include\pystate.h(209): note: see declaration of '_ts'
    src\wrapper.c(11493): error C2039: 'exc_traceback': is not a member of '_ts'
    c:\python37\include\pystate.h(209): note: see declaration of '_ts'
    src\wrapper.c(11536): error C2039: 'exc_type': is not a member of '_ts'
    c:\python37\include\pystate.h(209): note: see declaration of '_ts'
    src\wrapper.c(11537): error C2039: 'exc_value': is not a member of '_ts'
    c:\python37\include\pystate.h(209): note: see declaration of '_ts'
    src\wrapper.c(11538): error C2039: 'exc_traceback': is not a member of '_ts'
    c:\python37\include\pystate.h(209): note: see declaration of '_ts'
    src\wrapper.c(11539): error C2039: 'exc_type': is not a member of '_ts'
    c:\python37\include\pystate.h(209): note: see declaration of '_ts'
    src\wrapper.c(11540): error C2039: 'exc_value': is not a member of '_ts'
    c:\python37\include\pystate.h(209): note: see declaration of '_ts'
    src\wrapper.c(11541): error C2039: 'exc_traceback': is not a member of '_ts'
    c:\python37\include\pystate.h(209): note: see declaration of '_ts'
    error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2017\\Community\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.16.27023\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\python37\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Kristof\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-w04pgijy\\PyOpenGL-accelerate\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Kristof\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-w04pgijy\\PyOpenGL-accelerate\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\Kristof\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-1ulnpq1p\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile Check the logs for full command output.
```

### 3. Install PyOpenGL_accelerate   <sub>(SECOND ATTEMPT)</sub>

I download a pre-built package for Windows 64-bit:
https://pypi.org/project/PyOpenGL-accelerate/#files

There is no file for Python 3.7, so I take the latest one, which is for Python 3.4:
`PyOpenGL-accelerate-3.1.0.win-amd64-py3.4.exe`

Unfortunately the installation procedure stops with an error message: *Cannot find Python 3.4 installation*.

### 4. Install PyOpenGL_accelerate   <sub>(THIRD ATTEMPT)</sub>

I go back to the same download page:
https://pypi.org/project/PyOpenGL-accelerate/#files

And I download the source code:
`PyOpenGL-accelerate-3.1.0.zip (340.0 kB)`

Next I open a Windows terminal, navigate to the unzipped folder and run `setup.py` (Note: my Python 3.7 installation is located in `C:\Python37\` and I unzipped the folder in `C:\Python37\PyOpenGL-accelerate-3.1.0`):

```sh
C:\Users\Kristof>cd C:\Python37\PyOpenGL-accelerate-3.1.0

C:\Python37\PyOpenGL-accelerate-3.1.0>python setup.py install
running install
running bdist_egg
running egg_info
writing PyOpenGL_accelerate.egg-info\PKG-INFO
writing dependency_links to PyOpenGL_accelerate.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
writing top-level names to PyOpenGL_accelerate.egg-info\top_level.txt
reading manifest file 'PyOpenGL_accelerate.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
writing manifest file 'PyOpenGL_accelerate.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
installing library code to build\bdist.win-amd64\egg
running install_lib
running build_py
creating build
creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7
creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\OpenGL_accelerate
copying .\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\OpenGL_accelerate
running build_ext
skipping 'src\wrapper.c' Cython extension (up-to-date)
building 'OpenGL_accelerate.wrapper' extension
creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.7
creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release
creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\src
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -IC:\Python37\PyOpenGL-accelerate-3.1.0\.. -IC:\Python37\PyOpenGL-accelerate-3.1.0\src -IC:\Python37\PyOpenGL-accelerate-3.1.0 -IC:\Python37\include -IC:\Python37\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\ATLMFC\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.6.1\include\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\cppwinrt" /Tcsrc\wrapper.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\src\wrapper.obj
wrapper.c
src\wrapper.c(3919): warning C4244: '=': conversion from 'Py_ssize_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
src\wrapper.c(4376): warning C4244: '=': conversion from 'Py_ssize_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
src\wrapper.c(11474): error C2039: 'exc_type': is not a member of '_ts'
c:\python37\include\pystate.h(209): note: see declaration of '_ts'
src\wrapper.c(11475): error C2039: 'exc_value': is not a member of '_ts'
c:\python37\include\pystate.h(209): note: see declaration of '_ts'
src\wrapper.c(11476): error C2039: 'exc_traceback': is not a member of '_ts'
c:\python37\include\pystate.h(209): note: see declaration of '_ts'
src\wrapper.c(11488): error C2039: 'exc_type': is not a member of '_ts'
c:\python37\include\pystate.h(209): note: see declaration of '_ts'
src\wrapper.c(11489): error C2039: 'exc_value': is not a member of '_ts'
c:\python37\include\pystate.h(209): note: see declaration of '_ts'
src\wrapper.c(11490): error C2039: 'exc_traceback': is not a member of '_ts'
c:\python37\include\pystate.h(209): note: see declaration of '_ts'
src\wrapper.c(11491): error C2039: 'exc_type': is not a member of '_ts'
c:\python37\include\pystate.h(209): note: see declaration of '_ts'
src\wrapper.c(11492): error C2039: 'exc_value': is not a member of '_ts'
c:\python37\include\pystate.h(209): note: see declaration of '_ts'
src\wrapper.c(11493): error C2039: 'exc_traceback': is not a member of '_ts'
c:\python37\include\pystate.h(209): note: see declaration of '_ts'
src\wrapper.c(11536): error C2039: 'exc_type': is not a member of '_ts'
c:\python37\include\pystate.h(209): note: see declaration of '_ts'
src\wrapper.c(11537): error C2039: 'exc_value': is not a member of '_ts'
c:\python37\include\pystate.h(209): note: see declaration of '_ts'
src\wrapper.c(11538): error C2039: 'exc_traceback': is not a member of '_ts'
c:\python37\include\pystate.h(209): note: see declaration of '_ts'
src\wrapper.c(11539): error C2039: 'exc_type': is not a member of '_ts'
c:\python37\include\pystate.h(209): note: see declaration of '_ts'
src\wrapper.c(11540): error C2039: 'exc_value': is not a member of '_ts'
c:\python37\include\pystate.h(209): note: see declaration of '_ts'
src\wrapper.c(11541): error C2039: 'exc_traceback': is not a member of '_ts'
c:\python37\include\pystate.h(209): note: see declaration of '_ts'
error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2017\\Community\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.16.27023\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
```

### 5. My questions

I'm really stuck now. Please help:

- **Is `PyOpenGL` abandoned?**
  The latest pre-built executable dates back to the Python 3.4 era. That's more than 5 years ago. Why isn't there another update in so many years?
- **How do I get `PyOpenGL_accelerate` installed?**
  I've tried three different ways to install this thing. Can you help?

Answer (score 1):

I found unofficial Windows builds here:
https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pyopengl

I downloaded `PyOpenGL-3.1.3b2-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl` and `PyOpenGL_accelerate-3.1.3b2-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl`. Next, I navigate to my `Downloads` folder in a Windows terminal and start the installation:

```sh
C:\Users\Kristof>cd C:\Users\Kristof\Downloads

C:\Users\Kristof\Downloads>pip install PyOpenGL-3.1.3b2-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl
Processing c:\users\kristof\downloads\pyopengl-3.1.3b2-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl
Installing collected packages: PyOpenGL
Successfully installed PyOpenGL-3.1.3b2

C:\Users\Kristof\Downloads>pip install PyOpenGL_accelerate-3.1.3b2-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl
Processing c:\users\kristof\downloads\pyopengl_accelerate-3.1.3b2-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl
Installing collected packages: PyOpenGL-accelerate
Successfully installed PyOpenGL-accelerate-3.1.3b2
```

Thank you @Christoph Gohlke for maintaining those builds!